# How Can I set id menu?

Tags: mfc

I have:

```
CMenu menu;
CRect rc;
GetWindowRect(&rc);
VERIFY(menu.CreatePopupMenu());
menu.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, 0, _T("Cancella"));

menu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON, point.x + rc.left, point.y + rc.top, this);
```

but I do't know how I can set ID menu.

Comment: The id is the second parameter to AppendMenu(), where you pass 0.

But maybe that's not your question? Then please make your question a bit more precise.

Comment: so my iD is zero? I must use on_command to have an event when I click with mouse on menu..I use on_menuselect but it works when I am with cursor over menu:

Comment: ON_COMMAND(0, OnMenu)...it doesn't work my fuction

Comment: I have the function void OnMenu

Comment: Your menu does not need an ID. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
#define ID_MYACTION 42
menu.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_MYACTION, _T("Cancella"));
```

Then insert a message handler for this item like

```
// in your message map:
ON_COMMAND(ID_MYACTION, OnMyAction)

// the handler itself:
void CMyWnd::OnMyAction()
{
    // do what you like
}
```